# How to publish a website with Mercurial TortoiseHG enabled? (Error Unable to add .hgignore to the website. )

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, version-control, mercurial

How to implement version control along with visual studio? I am trying and currently stuck during publishing website.

**Details:**

- Using Mercurial Tortoise HG for source control along with Visual Studio 2010
- Working on a asp.net website (not web application)
- I did a right click on the website folder and created a new repository.

After creating the repository, Mercurial is adding `.hg` folder to my "website" folder.  Earlier I tried to publish and it didn't allowed me to publish because `.hg` folder was unknown.  So I made the folder hidden. And now whenever I try to publish the website it fails and the following error comes up.

> Unable to add '.hgignore' to the Web site.  Server error: '.hgignore' does not refer to a page or folder in this web.  It may be a page or folder in a subweb, or it could be a badly formed URL.Error: The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error

Am I adding files to the repositories the wrong way? Or should the `.hg` folder not be a part of the folder inside visual studio? Or what the right way to implement Mercurial with vs2010?

There is some common sense I am missing here.  Please help.

**UPDATE:** 
Resolved

I installed a plug in and then it solved the problem. And now when I open the folder there is no `[+]` sign on top of `.hg` folder.  Which means it was not supposed to be included in version control in the first place.  And it is not inside visual studio but originally when I did a right click and created a repository it was opening up as folder in vs2010 which in turn was failing my build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the `.hg` and `.hgignore` files included in your project? I wouldn't include them in my project and publish again.  Just right click on them and say exclude from project.  They are not needed.

Comment: @Kyle Rogers - But it is a website and I thought to make them hidden.  It would have worked had it been a website project(yes I regret choosing a website model).  And I don't want to port everything all over again.

Comment: The .hg folder and the .hgignore file are for your source control only.  They are not needed by your website in anyway.

Comment: But when we create repository these folders are created within the folder which has all website files.  So should we keep website files in a different place and .Hg files in different folder?  Because when I create a repository and open the project in vs those folders sit there.

Comment: @kyle Rogers - I installed a plug in and then it solved the problem.  And now when I open the folder there is no [+] sign on top of .Hg folder.  And it is not inside visual studio but when I did a right click and created a repository it was opening up as folder in vs2010.  Sorry to bother you but it helped.  Thanks.

Comment: If you have a website in say C:\website and inside this directory you do an 'hg init', yes it will create the .hg directory along with the .hgignore file.  However these files are not used by the website, IIS, or anything other than mercurial for source control.  You should not include those files in  your project as they have no relevance.

Comment: I got that part but those folders were added by default when I opened visual studio.  somehow I didn't knew how to exclude them from vs2010 in a website application.